# How to fit a HMM with two hidden states to sequences with R

Tags: r, hidden, hidden-markov-models, markov

In R, I need to fit an HMM with two hidden states to a set of sequences. There are 2 classes, with sets of sequences for each. I need to find out which class a certain test sequence is from, and what the hidden state sequence is for it. Here are subsets of the classes:

```
Class 1

QCQRPCWQVFYMWSMSLKEC

CHHVHHVIWYSMEPIWLGIY

HQGYGCSIKYGMYCDLYQLG

CTISQVDCAYPQGDLCGVCQ

QDGDGVWIMGKDMYISCYCK


Class 2

SESQQYWLAEPCEHGWWQCP

QNYSGMLVGWCHTQLSLQIF

QDGYLWWNALPHEDLSGFCQ

QCGGYNHNAEIHEKLSIWDF

GFGKMVWNPGPWESDSLDCF

Test sequence

YYCDGCWIAYHDQDLLVCCV
```

I have tried using the HMM package but I keep getting subscript out of bounds errors in Rstudio.